# How to get Custom Field data on WPGraphQL

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, headless, wp-graphql

**How to get Custom Field data on WPGraphQL**

I add a custom field for upload featured image for category. Now I want to get this value on WPGraphQL Query.

[image: How to get Custom Field data on WPGraphQL]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still have to register your custom field to the GraphQL schema using the `register_graphql_field()` function.

```
add_action( 'graphql_register_types', function() {
    register_graphql_field( 'PostCategory', 'categoryImage', [
        'type' => 'MediaItem',
        'resolve' => function( $post ) {
            $image = get_post_meta( $post->databaseId, 'category_image_id'  );
            return ! empty( $image ) ? $image : null;
        }
    ]);
});
```

Reference the WPGraphQL custom field recipes for more info [here](https://www.wpgraphql.com/recipes/recipe-tags/custom-fields/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this get all values of category.

```
get_option( "taxonomy_".$term_id );
```

Comment: want to get value on GraphQL Query not using PHP front end